# Pass unique id to Docker Compose service instance

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to deploy a third-party web application with front server acting like load balancer and multiple instances of the actual app server behind it. For reasons independent from me I must pass unique id to each app server instance, as environmental variable. My docker-compose.yml, simplified, is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  lb:
    image: lb_image
  app:
    image: app_image
    depends_on:
      - lb
    links:
      - "server:lb"
    environment:
      - LB_HOST=server
```

Now, I'd like to run:

```
docker-compose up -d --scale app=3
```

but passing to each instance different env variable value. I've heard of templating, it would be nice to have something like:

```
environment:
  - CONTAINER_ID={{.Node.Id}}
```

in my docker-compose.yml, is it possible (every solution I've heard of this far involves writing external script, which in my opinion totally discards benefits of using Compose)?

Comment: I want an answer to this too. In my case I want an incrementing unique worker ID passed into each instance. Did you get to a good solution in the end? What do you think is best?

Comment: guys - any luck? i am facing a similar situation and need help please.